# How can I create a rectangle with two-dimensional Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, rectangles, drawrectangle

In this exercise we have to draw a rectangle using two-dimensional arrays that goes from 10 to 15 rows and 20 to 30 column, putting in the border of the rectangle "#" while putting inside the rectangle "-". It has to look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOqY6.png

The code I have so far is this, but I need some help fixing it since I'm a bit lost with the exercise:

```
public class Practica9{
public static void main(String[] args){

    char [][] tablero = new char [10][20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){   
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            tablero [0][19] = #;
            tablero [9][19] = #;
            System.out.println (tablero[0][19]);
            System.out.println (tablero[9][19]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++){
            tablero [1][18] = -;
            tablero [8][18] = -;
            System.out.println (tablero [1][18]);
            System.out.println (tablero [8][18]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And how does your output look/differ from expected?

Comment: You'll have to replace `#` and `-` with `'#'` and `'-'`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      int rows = 15;
      int columns =30;
      char [][] rectangle = new char[rows][columns];
      // fill array
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                  if(i==0 || j==0  || i==rows-1 || j==columns-1){
                          rectangle[i][j] = '#';
                  }
                  else{
                           rectangle[i][j] = '-';
                  }
            }
      }
     // print array
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                  System.out.print(rectangle[i][j]);
            }
           System.out.println();
      }
}
```